# Read IO size for Kafka fetch request

Tags: apache-kafka

When a fetch request is made - the response size is limited by various Kafka parameters and they are well documented. But my question is - what is the read IO size at the core. A process must be opening the segment file and issue a read() operation and get the data into memory. The question is - what is the size of this read() - is it a fixed number or it is equal to - max.partition.fetch.bytes? If so, then if the partition has sufficient data one read IO will get enough data to feed the consumer for that partition. I tried looking into the source code, but could not figure out this size.

The reason I am doing this is - I am benchmarking my Kafka logs file system and for consumers I want to see at what read IO size the filesystem behaves better and want to see if Kafka fetches/polls show case the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two I/O's to your question: Disk i/o and Network i/o

**Disk i/o:**
Kafka leverages filesystem for the storage and cache.

If you are looking for the core disk I/O operation size, then it is typical block sizes, and most of the modern operating systems the block size defines by PageCache in general it is upto 4096bytes (ex $getconf PAGESIZE shows size on your server)

*In summary*: Virtual Memory pages map to Filesystem blocks, which map to Block Device sectors.

*Reference code*: [LogSegment.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogSegment.scala) internally uses [FileRecord.java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/FileRecords.java) which uses FileSystem call.

**Network i/o** next comes to the Consumer Fetch request,

Most of the time the Consumer FetchRequest fetches from (Hot data) PageCache on particular leader partition broker. Based on your consumer Kafka params (ex,Min/MaxBytes and maxWaitMs) it fills-up the NIC request from PageCache and transmit over the wire.

Reference code: [Fetcher.java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L237) ([ConsumerNetworkClient](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java))Client.send() and wait for NIC response.

This combination of pagecache and sendfile means that on a Kafka cluster where the consumers are mostly caught up and you will see no read activity on the disks whatsoever as they will be serving data entirely from cache. Because Kafka uses zero-copy data transfer (Broker → Consumer)

So, most of the performance tuning(apart from available memory for pagecache and disk i/o) you can play with consumer params like min wait time and max buffer size of packets.

Here are some of the points to consider for performance tuning on Consumption:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the default `ConsumerConfig` here:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.java

And how consumer fetches the data from kafka topics, is well defined in `Fetcher.java`

```
final FetchSessionHandler.FetchRequestData data = entry.getValue();
            final FetchRequest.Builder request = FetchRequest.Builder
                    .forConsumer(this.maxWaitMs, this.minBytes, data.toSend())
                    .isolationLevel(isolationLevel)
                    .setMaxBytes(this.maxBytes)
                    .metadata(data.metadata())
                    .toForget(data.toForget())
                    .rackId(clientRackId);
```

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L237

It has the default values for each property which is overridden by user input value from the config.

Comment: Thanks Nishu - yes these are limiting the total bytes fetched. What I am looking at is more on the partition in a given broker. For example I have a partition I have around 1GB of unread data and a fetch request comes from a consumer having   max.partition.fetch.bytes having 1MB size. If Kakfka honors that 1MB then on the broker side - how many read system calls will be fired to fetch that 1MB? Will it be a big Fat read IO of 1MB or it will be n number of 65K reads of x no of read IOs of size y.

Comment: kafka relies heavily on memory-mapping the segment files, which means it will be the operating system doing the reads - which makes it hard to say.
also - if the data is recent it will actually be serving from memory (page cache)

Comment: Hi Radai - thanks much and yes it does a lot of mmap ops, but I think main log is not read through mmap, otherwise it can't use cache heavily. It uses NIO and reads through a channel - the size of ByteBuffer should define the read length. The read may not lead to a physical IO to disk - but it would still make a read call to OS. What I am looking for is that size of read request. Does it rely on a config parameter or it is fixed value int?